# C++: Compiler doesn't see overloaded operator

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading, overloading

I have stuck on my try to implement linked list iterator class. Compiler is complaining when I use overloaded "!=" operator here:

```
for (itr = (test0.begin()); itr != (test0.end()); ++itr)
{
    cout << *itr;
}
```

Here is the error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator!=’ in ‘itr != SinglyLinkedList<Object>::end() [with Object = int]()’
```

I don't understand why it can't find the match, because both test0.end() and itr are iterators.

Here is the code of overloaded operator:

```
bool operator!= (iterator &rhs)
{
    return (this->current != rhs.current);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read a bit about const correctness and temporary objects and references.

Comment: begin() and end() will be returning a const iterator so your operator!=() signature needs changing.

Comment: Too many parentheses make code hard to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that this is because of const-correctness:

```
bool operator!= (iterator const &rhs) const
{
    return (this->current != rhs.current);
}
```